# Cannot create and open File using file handling

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am writing a basic code but run into an error when trying to open a file. I've had a rough break and am having to start from the basics. Following is the part of the code where I run into the error:

```
int main()
{
    string name; 
    fstream file; 
    cout << " Enter file name and type (E.g filname.txt) : "; 
    cin >> name; 
    file.open(name);
```

Following is the error:

> [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_fstream<char>::open(std::string&)'

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I am returning after a long break so I apologize for any inconsistencies.

Comment: This means you have an old compiler or at least one that is running in a mode prior to the c++11 / 2011 standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [`std::basic_fstream::open(std::string&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) overload isn't available you are probably compiling using some C++ version prior to C++11.

Make sure you compile using at least C++11 and it should be fine.

Comment: Or, just use `file.open(name.c_str());` instead

Answer (score -3):

you have to pass the open mode too.

Here is an example:

```
// print the content of a text file.
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream ifs;

  ifs.open ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);

  char c = ifs.get();

  while (ifs.good()) {
    std::cout << c;
    c = ifs.get();
  }

  ifs.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Code taken from [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/)

I suggest you to always check on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com)

It's very well documented!

Comment: "_you have to pass the open mode too_" - No you don't. `ios_base::in|ios_base::out` is the default open mode.

Comment: @Eric not when using an STL that doesn't have a `std::string` overload of `open()`